# How to use Android LocationManager and Listener

Tags: android, service, gps, locationmanager

I'm not having any luck receiving any data from the GPS using the code below, and i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, it seems like my code matches everything i see online. i'd like to eventually add this to a background service to log gps coordinates even when the activity isn't visible or if other apps are open and if the speed is greater than a certain defined amount, but at this point I can't even get any of the data to show up. i'm relatively new to android but i can't figure out what am i doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView textView;
MyLocationListener myLocationListener;
LocationManager lm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
    addLocationListener();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void addLocationListener()
{
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

    final String PROVIDER = lm.getBestProvider(c, true);

    this.myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    this.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 0.0F, this.myLocationListener);
    //lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0L, 0.0F, myLocationListener);
    Log.d("LOC_SERVICE", "Service RUNNING!");
}

public void updateLocation(Location location)
{
    double latitude, longitude;

    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    int mph = convertSpeed(location.getSpeed());
    Log.d("LOC_SERVICE", "mph: "+mph);
    this.textView.setText(this.textView.getText()+"\n"+"lat: "+latitude+" lng: "+longitude+" mph: "+mph);
}


private int convertSpeed(float speed) {
    int mph =(int)(2.236936D * speed);
    return mph;
}


class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("LOC_SERVICE", "Listener RUNNING!");
        updateLocation(location);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, just that you need to remove the location listener in `onDestroy`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use permission first:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Next you inside onCreate() method use below code to get access to GPS.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            2000, 1, this);

}
```

Now if GPS is not enabled then you need to refer below code. For detailed explanation, you can refer how to get[DEAD LINK] [current location in android][1](http://techlovejump.com/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) tutorial.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
         startActivity(intent);
```

Here we have used intents to redirect user to location settings page so that he can enable the GPS under location settings.

Comment: that intent is a nice touch

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this easily. you have to write code in main activity. and Main activity implements Locationlistner interface. and overload its four methods. here i'am retrieving my Longitude and Latitide co-ordinates in a textview when application started. and you have to give permission for access location in your manifest file.

as under my code.

```
package com.nisarg.gpsdemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
 private TextView textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double longitude=location.getLongitude();
        double latitude=location.getLatitude();
        textview.setText("Longitude:   "+longitude+"   Latitide:  "+latitude);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

and you have to give permission like this in manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

And last warning.
you have to give permission to your application and start mobile data and GPS before you open application. either it will be crashed.

that's it.
hope it will help you. :)